# Pair inside priority queue

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, std-pair

I am trying to store pairs in priority queue and I am using a compare function that compares second value of each pair.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;

class CompareDist
{
public:
    bool operator()(pair<int,int> n1,pair<int,int> n2) {
        return n1.second>n2.second;
    }
};
int main()
{
    priority_queue<pair<int,int>,CompareDist> pq;
}
```

When I compile this I get an error

```
error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘class CompareDist’
```

What could be the reason.I am new to STL.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is what [priority_queue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) looks like:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Container = std::vector<T>, 
    class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>
> class priority_queue;
```

In other words, `CompareDist` should be the **third** argument and the second argument should be the container (which has `value_type`), like the following:

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>,CompareDist> pq;
```

Notice also, that `priority_queue` is what is called a "container adaptor". Another container is used as the underlying container and the priority_queue has special members functions for accessing it. Another example of a container adaptor would be std::stack.

Answer (score 4):

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>,vector<pair<int,int>>,CompareDist> pq;
```

you need to provide second argument for the inbuilt template of priority_queue.